# Binding CustomControl to own properties

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, custom-controls

I'm driving myself nuts on this... I'm trying to provide my control with the simple ability to define an own color.

**My control:**

That's my xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="starTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Viewbox>
                <Path x:Name="star"
                      Data="F1 M 145.637,174.227L 127.619,110.39L 180.809,70.7577L 114.528,68.1664L 93.2725,5.33333L 70.3262,67.569L 4,68.3681L 56.0988,109.423L 36.3629,172.75L 91.508,135.888L 145.637,174.227 Z"
                      Fill="LightGray" />
            </Viewbox>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="star" Property="Fill" Value="Yellow" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0"
                  Click="RatingButtonClickEventHandler"
                  Cursor="Hand"
                  Tag="1"
                  Template="{StaticResource starTemplate}" />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"
                  Click="RatingButtonClickEventHandler"
                  Cursor="Hand"
                  Tag="2"
                  Template="{StaticResource starTemplate}" />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2"
                  Click="RatingButtonClickEventHandler"
                  Cursor="Hand"
                  Tag="3"
                  Template="{StaticResource starTemplate}" />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="3"
                  Click="RatingButtonClickEventHandler"
                  Cursor="Hand"
                  Tag="4"
                  Template="{StaticResource starTemplate}" />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="4"
                  Click="RatingButtonClickEventHandler"
                  Cursor="Hand"
                  Tag="5"
                  Template="{StaticResource starTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

Now when I bind the `Path.Fill` property like `Fill="{Binding Path=UnselectedColor"` I'd need to specify the DataContext of the control to itself:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(RatingControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow)));

    public RatingControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
```

This would work and I can define the color from my control, but it would destroy any other bindings.

**Back from the custom control to my implementation:**

For example the following code would set the `SelectedColor` and `UnselectedColor`, but the binding of `RatingValue="{Binding Path=Rating}` would fail since it tries to bind to property `Rating` in my `RatingControl` instead of the property in my ViewModel.

```
<my:RatingControl Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  RatingValue="{Binding Path=Rating,
                                        TargetNullValue='0.0',
                                        Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedColor="Orange"
                  ToolTip="Bewertung"
                  UnselectedColor="LightGray" />
```

That's the binding error. `Extension` is a property in my ViewModel and it contains a *double* property `Rating` that I'm trying to bind:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'UnselectedColor' property not found on 'object' ''Extension' (HashCode=24138614)'. BindingExpression:Path=UnselectedColor; DataItem='Extension' (HashCode=24138614); target element is 'Path' (Name=''); target property is 'Fill' (type 'Brush')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `DataContext` in the wrong manner. Please read [Simple Pattern for Creating Re-useable UserControls](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/).

For short it should be

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
```

and

```
public RatingControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
public RatingControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

you bound **DataContext** of **RatingControl** to itself and every databinding on your control, if no change of dataContext later happens, will bind to **RatingControl**'s properties. That's why the **Rating** binding doens't work (there is no **Rating** in **RatingControl**). I think you should remove `DataContext = this;` in **RatingControl**'s constructor, and try to bind **Fill** property to **SelectedColor** property of **RatingControl** with following code on **RatingControl** *XAML*:

```
Fill="{Binding ElementName=<nameOfRatingControl>, SelectedColor}"
```

This link would help you have an overview about dataBinding: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to bind to self, you can use [Binding.RelativeSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx).

See also:

- [RelativeSource MarkupExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx)
- [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I can't do anything with your answer to help me with my problem.

Comment: @SeToY Remove `DataContext = this` line, bind using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=my:RatingControl}` when you need to refer to properties of the control in its template or style.